# using sort selection with an array of structs in c++

Tags: c++

I can't figure out how to get the sort selection working. I have to sort the scores (doubles) from the struct in ascending order.

Here is my code, I will comment where i am getting the errors.

My struct:

```
struct diveInfo   
{
    string diversName;
    double totalScore;
    double totalScore;
    double diff;
    double scores[NUM_SCORES];
};
```

My function to sort the scores in ascending order:

```
void selectionSort(diveInfo *ptr,  int size)
{
    diveInfo temp;

    double minValue;

    int startScan;
    int minIndex;

    for ( startScan = 0; startScan < (size - 1); startScan++)
    {
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = ptr[startScan].scores; //keep getting an error here saying type double cannot be assigned to an entity of type double.
        temp = ptr[startScan];

        for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
        {
            if ( ptr[index].scores < minValue) 
            {
                temp = ptr[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }

        }
        ptr[minIndex] = ptr[startScan];
        ptr[startScan] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: scores is an array. Do you perhaps want to sort on the totalScore? You do need to think about what you are doing. It should be clear that assigning an array of doubles to a double is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

`scores` is array of doubles, you need to specify index in this array to access specific double value.
For example `minValue = ptr[startScan].scores[0];`

Answer (score 1):

```
minValue = ptr[startScan].scores;
```

`scores` is an array of doubles. arrayname acts as a pointer as well. `scores` is of type `double*` [precisely one that can point to an array of size `NUM_SCORES`]
You are assigning a `double` pointer to an int.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to assign double* (an array of doubles is a double*) to a double.

You can try changing your array of doubles into a `vector` of doubles. Then you can sort them using `std::sort` or `std::stable_sort`.